# A temp table column not recognized in a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to insert a bulk of data into a temp table and process it then insert it into another table then drop the temp table.

I'm using this code

```
USE [fmctest]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[HOSPITAL_LOCATION_INSTEAD_OF_INSERT]
ON [dbo].[HOSPITAL_LOCATION] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP]
        (
            HOSPITAL_LOCATION_ID [varchar](max) NULL,
            NAME [varchar](max) NULL,
            DIVISION [varchar](max) NULL,
            STOP_CODE_NUMBER [varchar](max) NULL,
            INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR [varchar](max) NULL,
            INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH [varchar](max) NULL,
            INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY [varchar](max) NULL,
            TYPE_OF_LOCATION [varchar](max) NULL,
         ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP]
        SELECT 
            REPLACE(HOSPITAL_LOCATION_ID, '"', ''),
            REPLACE(NAME, '"', ''),
            REPLACE(DIVISION, '"', ''),
            REPLACE(STOP_CODE_NUMBER, '"', ''),
            REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR, '"', ''),
            REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH, '"', ''),
            REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY, '"', ''), 
            REPLACE(ADMINISTER_INPATIENT_MEDS, '"', ''),
            REPLACE(TYPE_OF_LOCATION, '"', '')
        FROM 
            INSERTED;

    UPDATE [HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP]
    SET INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR = '1900',
        INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH = '1',
        INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY = '1'
    WHERE INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR = '';

    INSERT INTO dbo.HOSPITAL_LOCATION
        SELECT 
            HOSPITAL_LOCATION_ID, NAME,
            DIVISION, STOP_CODE_NUMBER,
            CONCAT(INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR, '-', INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH, '-', INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY),
            ADMINISTER_INPATIENT_MEDS,
            TYPE_OF_LOCATION,
            CONVERT(varchar,getdate(), 20)
        FROM 
            dbo.[HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP];

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.[HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP];
END
```

These are the errors I get:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure HOSPITAL_LOCATION_INSTEAD_OF_INSERT, Line 38 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Invalid column name 'INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure HOSPITAL_LOCATION_INSTEAD_OF_INSERT, Line 39 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Invalid column name 'INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure HOSPITAL_LOCATION_INSTEAD_OF_INSERT, Line 40 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Invalid column name 'INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY'.

What did I miss ?

I tried to separate this trigger with 2 triggers instead of insert and insert trigger, but I want to make the schema simpler.

Comment: You can use cte instead of create table.i not sure can use table temp (#tablename)

Comment: The `INSERT INTO [dbo].[HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP] SELECT` query has 9 columns but the  table has only 8 columns.

Comment: I think you need to step back and take another look at what you are attempting to do here.  The only thing this trigger is doing is attempting to 'fix' the data coming from the bulk insert.  That should be done as part of the import process - not in a trigger.  But if you must do it in a trigger then all you need to do is perform those in a normal insert trigger - updating the values in the virtual table 'inserted'.

Comment: The table probably already exist but contains wrong columns? btw, it's better to use a real temporary table (create table #t_something), the way you do it is a bit dangerous if multiple rows are inserted from different places. Also, you can do what you're doing directly in the insert, no need to waste time on extra tables

Comment: THe use of an intermediary table heere is not necessary and a serious impact on performance - as is the gratutious use of varchar(max) columns.

Comment: Show us the table definition for `HOSPITAL_LOCATION`. Looking at your last INSERT statement it would appear that it has a single column for `INACTIVATE_DATE` (or similar), so it would make sense that the SELECT from `inserted` complains that it doesn't know what the `INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR`, `INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH` and `INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY` columns are.

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi sorry what is cte ?

Comment: @DanGuzman in the temp table i got 3 columns which is a divided date to be one column in the other table and a audit column with date which make the difference that you've mentioned .

this method i have did but didn't work for dates

Comment: @Jeff thanks for replaying can you explain how can i do this in the import process please .

Comment: Can you send structure table dbo.HOSPITAL_LOCATION? .explain cte https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cte/

Comment: @alhadrusi - it depends on how you are importing this data.  If you are using SSIS - then transform the data using a data transformation task.  If you are importing using BULK INSERT or BCP or something like that, then import into a staging table and then insert from staging into final using whatever data manipulation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code based on the information of your post I had. The information was incomplete (because I did not have the structure of the HOSPITAL_LOCATION table and information filed insert).
But try not to use a trigger for anything

```
alter  TRIGGER [dbo].[HOSPITAL_LOCATION_INSTEAD_OF_INSERT]
ON [dbo].[HOSPITAL_LOCATION] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
          
    -- Insert statements for trigger here

  with _HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP as (
        SELECT 
            REPLACE(HOSPITAL_LOCATION_ID, '"', '') as HOSPITAL_LOCATION_ID,
            REPLACE(NAME, '"', '') as NAME,
            REPLACE(DIVISION, '"', '') as DIVISION,
            REPLACE(STOP_CODE_NUMBER, '"', '') as STOP_CODE_NUMBER,
           Case when REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR, '"', '') = '' then '1900'
                else   REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR, '"', '') end as INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR,

          Case when  REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR, '"', '') = '' then '1'
          else REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH, '"', '') end as INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH,

          Case when  REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR, '"', '') = '' then '1' else  
          REPLACE(INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY, '"', '') end as INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY, 
            REPLACE(ADMINISTER_INPATIENT_MEDS, '"', '') as ADMINISTER_INPATIENT_MEDS,
            REPLACE(TYPE_OF_LOCATION, '"', '') as TYPE_OF_LOCATION
        FROM 
            INSERTED
            )
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.HOSPITAL_LOCATION
    (HOSPITAL_LOCATION_ID,NAME,DIVISION,
    STOP_CODE_NUMBER,INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR_INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH_INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY
    ,ADMINISTER_INPATIENT_MEDS,TYPE_OF_LOCATION,createdate
    )
        SELECT 
             HOSPITAL_LOCATION_ID
            ,NAME,
            DIVISION,
            STOP_CODE_NUMBER,
            CONCAT(INACTIVATE_DATE_YEAR, '-', INACTIVATE_DATE_MONTH, '-', INACTIVATE_DATE_DAY),
            ADMINISTER_INPATIENT_MEDS,
            TYPE_OF_LOCATION,
            CONVERT(varchar,getdate(), 20)
        FROM 
          _HOSPITAL_LOCATION_TEMP;

END
```

---

Disadvantages of the trigger

1.When you use BULK INSERT to insert data into a table, triggers are not fired unless you include the FIRE_TRIGGERS option in your bulk insert statement.

2.Triggers are difficult to locate unless you have proper documentation because they are invisible to the client.

3.Triggers add overhead to DML statements.

4.The problem of using triggers for audit purposes is that when triggers are enabled, they execute always regardless of the circumstances that caused the trigger to fire.

---

limitations on triggers:

1.A table can have a maximum of three triggers: one update trigger, one insert trigger, and one delete trigger.

2.Each trigger can apply to only one table. However, a single trigger can apply to all three user actions: update, insert, and delete.

3.You cannot create a trigger on a view or on a temporary table, though triggers can reference views or temporary tables.

4.The writetext statement will not activate insert or update triggers.

5.Although a truncate table statement is, in effect, like a delete without a where clause, because it removes all rows, it cannot fire a trigger, because individual row deletions are not logged.

6.You cannot create a trigger or build an index or a view on a temporary object (@object)

7.You cannot create triggers on system tables. If you try to create a trigger on a system table, Adaptive Server returns an error message and cancels the trigger.

8.You cannot use triggers that select from a text column or an image column of the inserted or deleted table.

9.If Component Integration Services is enabled, triggers have limited usefulness on proxy tables because you cannot examine the rows being inserted, updated, or deleted (via the inserted and deleted tables). You can create a trigger on a proxy table, and it can be invoked. However, deleted or inserted data is not written to the transaction log for proxy tables because the insert is passed to the remote server. Hence, the inserted and deleted tables, which are actually views to the transaction log, contain no data for proxy tables.

Comment: thanks a lot for all provided information and explanations your answer is the one !